# Java calendar time, minute is wrong

Tags: java, time

Anyone know why the MINUTE method in java.util.Caldendar returns an incorrect minute?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Clock
{
    // Instance fields
    private Calendar time;

    /**
     * Constructor. Starts the clock at the current operating system time
     */
    public Clock()
    {
       System.out.println(this.time.HOUR_OF_DAY+":"+this.time.MINUTE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yet another example of how bad Java's Date + Calender API is...

Comment: any idea in defence of why it is the way it is?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 26):

Calendar.MINUTE isn't the actual minute but rather a constant index value to pass into "get()" in order to get the value.  For example:

```
System.out.println(this.time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + this.time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Comment: I imagine not being used to Javadoc conventions,
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY
is a bit ambiguous.

"Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22."

Answer (score 9):

`HOUR_OF_DAY` and `MINUTE` are public static fields that are meant to be passed into `Calendar#get(int)`. Typically, you'd want to use `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)` for the current minute. In your example though, you want `time.get(Calendar.MINUTE)`.

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Clock
{
    // Instance fields
    private Calendar time;

```
/**
 * Constructor. Starts the clock at the current operating system time
 */
public Clock()
{
   time = Calendar.getInstance(); 
   System.out.println(this.time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) +
                       ":" + this.time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}
```

}

----------------0---------------
;)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
             .getMinute()
```

> 34
> ( if current moment were 2016-01-23T12:34:56.789-05:00[America/Montreal] )

## Details

The other Answers are correct.

### java.time

The modern way to do this work is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );  // zdt.toString(): 2016-01-23T12:34:56.789-05:00[America/Montreal]
int minute = zdt.getMinute();  // 34
```

---

### About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).