# When to use self

Tags: swift

I got a simple question that is not really trying to solve a problem but is asked out of curiosity.

Say this is whats in my GameScene.swift file:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

     //Some global properties 
     let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")
     var score = Int()

     override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

         //Way 1 (which I see most of the time)
         player.position.....
         score = 1

        //Way 2 (which I see sometimes)
        self.player.position...
        self.score = 1
}
```

What is the school of though behind self? I have seen some tutorials where people like to use self to be explicit. However most tutorials do not use self and I have even seen 1 tutorial where the guy said that unless self is explicitly needed (not sure what that means) you shouldn't use self.

Could someone please clear me up of wether I should use Way 1 or Way 2 and what the difference is? 
I appreciate any replies, thank you

Update

After coding for over 1 year now I actually prefer way 1 as member djeck has explained in his answer. 
I am only using self when I am required by the compiler. I think it makes code easier to read and it is also easier to identify when you have to use unowned self or weak self

Comment: It's a matter of personal reference. I like the second way because it is apparent at a glance that I'm modifying an instance variable. With the first way, you don't know if `player` is local to the func or belong to the class.

Comment: Some similar questions with other languages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406053/in-java-why-do-people-prepend-fields-with-this (Java) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732045/what-is-a-good-rule-for-when-to-prepend-members-with-this-c (C#). At the end of the day, it boils down to personal style. Don't overthink it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a style preference and might not be suitable for stackoverflow's Q/A format but [Ray Wenderlich](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide) has a style guide for this.

> For conciseness, avoid using self since Swift does not require it to access an object's properties or invoke its methods.
>
> Use self when required to differentiate between property names and arguments in initializers, and when referencing properties in closure expressions (as required by the compiler):

Comment: Link is outdated. New Link: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide